# autohotkey: How to make right mouse key mimic itself and the functions of left mousekey at same time?

Tags: autohotkey

aka RButton should activate both LButton and Rbutton's native functions based on whether it is held down or clicked.

```
~Rbutton::
send {lbutton down}{rbutton down}
return
```

This only works if I hold Rbutton down. When I release....Lbutton continues to press itself cause its still pressed down....I have to tap it to stop. It also doesn't address at all the single click function of mousekeys. Mouse is not like keyboard presses. I'm confused when the community acts like they are. Mouse has helddown state and it has single press state. I want both of these states translated over.

When rbutton is held it should also hold Lbutton. when rbutton is released it should also release lbutton. The above code activates when rbutton is pressed....so I'm guessing any usage of

If GetKeyState("RButton", "P")
send {lbutton down}
return

has to take place outside it. But this doesn't work outside of it. So do i use if not getkeystate()....well that is going to destroy the native function of LButton which is also a no-no. There should be no key destruction only key addition, I want to add Lbutton's workings to Rbutton. period.

Answer (score 1):

```
~RButton::LButton
```

Seems to work. I'm confused as to why, and what this syntax is. I thought the solution would involve the Send, and its scripting of {click right mouse}{click right down}?

Comment: Check out [hotkey modifiers](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols). This script effectively saying: "When `RButton` is pressed, still send the `RButton` input, but also send an `LButton` while you are at it"